# Parsing JSON in Python and AngularJS

Tags: python, json, angularjs

I'm experiencing some difficulties when parsing a JSON object sent from AngularJS to Python (Google App Engine).

The AngularJS code:

```
var article = { name: 'car' };
$http.put("articles", article);
```

The python code:

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

import os
import webapp2
import logging
import json 

class ArticleHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def put(self):
        data = self.request

        logging.error(data)
        #x = json.dumps(data)   
        #y = json.loads(data)
```

The error-log returns {"name":"car"}

json.dumps(data) raises: TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")

and

json.loads(data) raises: TypeError: expected string or buffer

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Somewhat embarrassingly, the solution was simple

    json.loads(self.request.body)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to parse a [Request](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/webapp/requestclass) object as json data.  Try parsing the body instead:

`json.loads(self.request.body)`